# I need help re writing one additional DB Query originally written with Squeel, I tried various syntax but can't seem to get it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, activerecord

I need help re-writing one additional DB Query that was originally written with a gem called Squeel.  This one uses just slightly different syntax from the others and I thought I could just adapt what I had but it doesn't seem to be working.

I have been re-writing an application called Emissions Gateway from Rails v3.2 to Rails v6.1.4.2.  The DB Queries are where I keep getting stuck.

Here is the Squeel query:

```
Project.joins{vendor}.joins{certifications.outer}.where{
       (projects.vendor_id.eq my{ vendor_id }) |
       (vendors.parent_vendor_id.eq my{ vendor_id }) |
       ((certifications.donaldson == true) & (certifications.published == true))
     }.uniq
```

Here is the Rails v3.2 SQL out of the console.

```
SELECT DISTINCT "vendors".* FROM "vendors" 
INNER JOIN "projects" ON "projects"."vendor_id" = "vendors"."id" 
INNER JOIN "certifications" ON "certifications"."project_id" = "projects"."id" 
WHERE (("certifications"."donaldson" = 't' AND "certifications"."published" = 't')) 
ORDER BY "vendors"."parent_vendor_id", "vendors"."name"
```

I tried:

```
Project.joins(vendor: :certifications).where(certifications: { donaldson: 't', published: 't' })
.order(:parent_vendor_id, :name)
```

and I tried:

```
Project.joins(:vendor, :certifications).where(certifications: { donaldson: 't', published: 't' })
.order(:parent_vendor_id, :name)
```

Project.rb model (just the association portion and the schema information)

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: projects
#
#  id                :integer          not null, primary key
#  vendor_id         :integer
#  fleet_id          :integer
#  status            :string(255)      default("incomplete")
#  created_at        :datetime         not null
#  updated_at        :datetime         not null
#  user_id           :integer
#  notes             :text
#  user_verified_id  :integer
#  user_submitted_id :integer
#  certified         :boolean
#  cached_user_name  :string(255)
#  deleted           :boolean          default(FALSE)
#  cached_fleet_name :string(255)
#
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :status, :fleet_id, :vendor_id, :notes, :user_verified_id, :user_created_id, :user_submitted_id, :certified, :user_id, :engine_completed, :vehicle_completed, :inspection_completed, :maintenance_completed, :deleted, :cached_fleet_name, :cached_user_name, :cached_vehicle_number

  has_one :assessment, dependent: :destroy
  has_one :controlled_sale, dependent: :destroy
  has_one :datalogger, dependent: :destroy
  has_one :estimate, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :audits, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :certifications, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :filters, through: :certifications
  has_many :kits, through: :certifications
  has_many :pictures, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :warranties, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :work_orders, dependent: :destroy

  belongs_to :fleet
  belongs_to :user, touch: true
  belongs_to :vendor
  belongs_to :verified_by, :class_name => "User", :foreign_key => "user_verified_id"
  belongs_to :submitted_by, :class_name => "User", :foreign_key => "user_submitted_id"

  delegate :status, :complete?, to: :datalogger, prefix: true, allow_nil: true
  delegate :name, to: :vendor, prefix: true
  delegate :name, to: :user, prefix: true, allow_nil: true
  delegate :name, to: :verified_by, prefix: true, allow_nil: true
  delegate :name, to: :submitted_by, prefix: true, allow_nil: true

  before_create :cache_associated_data
  before_update :cache_user_name, :if => :user_id_changed?
  before_update :cache_fleet_name, :if => :fleet_id_changed?
  after_create :audit_create
  after_update :audit, :if => :status_changed?
  after_update :audit_reassignment, :if => :user_id_changed?
  after_update :audit_destroy, :if => :vendor_id_changed?
  after_update :devalidation_notice, :if => :certified_changed?
  after_update :locking_detection, :if => :status_changed?
  after_update :prepared_notice, :if => :status_changed?

  validates_presence_of :vendor_id
  validates_presence_of :user_id, :unless => :deleted?
  validates_presence_of :fleet_id, :unless => :deleted?
```

The vendor.rb model Schema and associationjs:

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: vendors
#
#  id                :integer          not null, primary key
#  name              :string(255)
#  address           :string(255)
#  contact           :string(255)
#  email             :string(255)
#  phone             :string(255)
#  note              :string(255)
#  user_manager_id   :integer
#  created_at        :datetime         not null
#  updated_at        :datetime         not null
#  logo_file_name    :string(255)
#  logo_content_type :string(255)
#  logo_file_size    :integer
#  logo_updated_at   :datetime
#  parent_vendor_id  :integer
#  street            :string(255)
#  street2           :string(255)
#  city              :string(255)
#  state             :string(255)
#  zip               :integer
#  country           :string(255)
#  region            :string(255)
#

class Vendor < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :phone, :contact, :email, :street, :street2, :city, :state, :zip, :country, :logo, :note, :addresses_attributes, :parent_vendor_id, :user_manager_id, :region_id, :users_attributes

  has_many :articles
  has_many :projects, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :fleets, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :users, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :subvendors, foreign_key: "parent_vendor_id", class_name: 'Vendor'
  has_many :verifications, dependent: :destroy
  has_one :subscription, dependent: :destroy
  alias_method :original_subscription, :subscription

  # certain regions are restricted to select subvendors
  has_many :regions
  # this vendors region
  belongs_to :region

  belongs_to :manager, foreign_key: "user_manager_id", class_name: 'User'
  belongs_to :parent_vendor, foreign_key: "parent_vendor_id", class_name: 'Vendor'
  belongs_to :fleet, touch: true

  # CHANGED (allow_blank:true removed) v0.005 9/2/2021 Scott Milella
  # delegate :name, to: :manager, prefix: true, allow_blank: true, allow_nil: true
  # delegate :name, to: :region, prefix: true, allow_blank: true, allow_nil: true
  delegate :name, to: :manager, prefix: true, allow_nil: true
  delegate :name, to: :region, prefix: true, allow_nil: true


  before_validation :sanitize

  validates_presence_of :phone, :email, :street, :city, :state, :zip, :country
  validates_presence_of :contact, message: "name for owner cannot be blank"
  validates_presence_of :name, message: "of company can't be blank"
  validates_presence_of :region_id, :if => :region_required?

  validates :name, exclusion: { in: ['donaldson', 'diesel emissions service', 'trash'] }

  validates_format_of :phone,
      :message => "must be a valid telephone number.",
      :with => /[0-9]{10}|[(]{1}[0-9]{0,3}[) -]{0,3}?[0-9]{3}[ -]{0,4}?[0-9]{4}/

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :users, reject_if: :all_blank
```

The certification.rb model with schema and association information:

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: certifications
#
#  id         :integer          not null, primary key
#  project_id :integer
#  filter_id  :integer
#  kit_id     :integer
#  created_at :datetime         not null
#  updated_at :datetime         not null
#  published  :boolean          default(FALSE)
#

class Certification < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :project, touch: true
  belongs_to :filter
  belongs_to :kit
  attr_accessible :project_id, :filter_id, :donaldson, :cdti, :published, :published_at
  validates_uniqueness_of :filter_id, scope: :project_id
```

I added the models because I am getting an error anytime I try to:
Project.joins(vendor: :certifications) I am getting an error:

```
Can't join 'Certification' to association named 'vendor'; perhaps you misspelled it?
```

When I look at the certification model, it doesn't appear to have a relationship with vendor, it belongs to project.

When I look at the vendor model, it has many projects

When I look at Project it seems to be the item that has associations to both, it has many :certifications, and it belongs to :vendor

I have tried numerous way to tell Rails to Project.joins(vendor: :certifications) but it just keeps giving me an error with project trying to join those two tables, yet a relationship exists and clearly it works somehow using that Squeel gem?  Syntax issue?

Any help will be greatly appreciated, I believe this is the last issue for this APP and I am done.
Thank you in advance,
Scott

Answer (score 0):

```
Vendor
       .joins(:projects, :certifications)
       .where(
          certifications: { 
            # use a boolean and let the DB adapter cast it
            donaldson: true, 
            published: true 
          }
       )
       .order(:parent_vendor_id, :name) 
       .destinct
```

Comment: I am getting an error saying ActiveRecord::ConfigurationError at /
Can't join 'Vendor' to association named 'certifications'; perhaps you misspelled it?  I tried reversing it to certifications: :vendor, I tried adding and removing s's from the models, I even tried adding a has_many between Vendor and certifications but it just keeps giving me the exact same error.  I hate that Squeel gem I don't know how it was joining those tables together, the SQL is saying it was somehow?  Any ideas?  I added the 3 models as far as the schema and associations in case there is something helpful.

Comment: Ah you want `.joins(:vendor, :certifications)`.

Comment: I am so confused as I tried something just like that at the beginning, it is working, with the exception of the .order is it giving an error saying: PG::InvalidColumnReference: ERROR:  for SELECT DISTINCT, ORDER BY expressions must appear in select list
LINE 1: ...ished" = $2 AND "projects"."status" = $3 ORDER BY vendors.pa...  It cuts off there for some reason.

Comment: GOT IT! Project.joins(:vendor, :certifications)
      .where(certifications: { 
            # use a boolean and let the DB adapter cast it
            donaldson: true, 
            published: true 
          })
      .order("vendors.parent_vendor_id", :name)

Comment: Thanks a million @max, I was so close, I completely missed the fact I was on a different table for the order, I think had I had that correct it might have worked, or at least been closer, I thank you SO MUCH for your time and explanations!  :)

Comment: It's pulling the wrong name information, I must still have something wrong on the order..

Comment: The SQL is using `vendors.name`, `.order("vendors.parent_vendor_id", :name)` would generate `projects.name`.

Comment: I had to add one beginning query and it now seems to be pulling the correct information, you were right on the :name, this is what is working, does this look right to you? Project.joins(:vendor, :certifications).where(projects: {vendor_id: vendor_id})
      .and(Project.joins(:vendor, :certifications))
      .where(certifications: { donaldson: 't', published: 't' })
      .order("vendors.parent_vendor_id", "vendors.name")

Comment: No it doesn't.  You should not have to repeat the entire query in the ` .and(...)` segment. I would just look at the SQL and not the sqeel code which is just batshit crazy. I still don't understand what sort of  witchcraft turns those three expressions in the block passed to where into the `ON` conditions for the two joins and a where clause. Its like they broke the entire Ruby language and built a DSL out of the flaming wreckage.

Comment: I don't for the life of me know WHY someone would want to integrate a GEM like Squeel because if they stop developing it (and they did) you have USELESS code, I would have this app converted 3 weeks ago if not for that gem.  Hate it.  Thank Max for all your help.  It is working somehow and actually working a hair better, I noticed on the original a few IDs were not pulling up correct, now they are.

Comment: This is the SQL that is coming out now: SELECT "vendors".* FROM "vendors" INNER JOIN "projects" ON "projects"."vendor_id" = "vendors"."id" INNER JOIN "certifications" ON "certifications"."project_id" = "projects"."id" WHERE "certifications"."donaldson" = $1 AND "certifications"."published" = $2 ORDER BY "vendors"."parent_vendor_id" ASC, "vendors"."name" ASC  [["donaldson", true], ["published", true]]

Comment: Almost right. Its missing `DESTINCT`.

Comment: If I add .distinct I get: PG::InvalidColumnReference: ERROR:  for SELECT DISTINCT, ORDER BY expressions must appear in select list
LINE 1: ...$2 AND "certifications"."published" = $3 ORDER BY vendors.pa...

Comment: Ah, right you should be basing the query of Vendor if you want to select the rows off vendor and not project.

Comment: So that means I should be joining Vendor.joins(:project, :certifications) ?  Is that what you mean?

Comment: If I try it the way you changed the answer to I get the error: ActiveRecord::ConfigurationError at /projects
Can't join 'Vendor' to association named 'project'; perhaps you misspelled it?

Comment: Yes, you start the query off the model you want in the result set. It should be projects in plural - my bad.

Comment: I am now getting the error: Can't join 'Vendor' to association named 'certification'; perhaps you misspelled it? I tried :certifications and :certification both seem to do the same?

Comment: It's in the projects section of the APP and the one I had working is so close, it is 5 projects off and I think that is because I can't get distinct to work on it, but I could be wrong, this stuff is so difficult to me. The rest of the code I am good with, these DB queries are were I struggle.

Comment: is there a way I can do the entire query in the pure SQL like it came out of the Rails 3.2 console?

Comment: I GOT IT WORKING!  The project numbers, statuses, published, everything is matching from the OLD APP to the new, this is the syntax nightmare that made it work:  Project.joins(vendor: { projects: :certifications })
      .where(projects: {vendor_id: vendor_id}, certifications: { donaldson: true, published: true }).distinct

Comment: SQL output, vendor and the project are in slightly different orders but works!, Do you see anything wrong with this @max?   SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT "projects"."id") FROM "projects" INNER JOIN "vendors" ON "vendors"."id" = "projects"."vendor_id" INNER JOIN "projects" "projects_vendors" ON "projects_vendors"."vendor_id" = "vendors"."id" INNER JOIN "certifications" ON "certifications"."project_id" = "projects_vendors"."id" WHERE "projects"."vendor_id" = $1 AND "certifications"."donaldson" = $2 AND "certifications"."published" = $3  [["vendor_id", 3], ["donaldson", true], ["published", true]]